# Why is this Python array not slicing?

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice, intervals

Initial data is:

```py
array([[0.0417634 ],
   [0.04493844],
   [0.04932728],
   [0.04601787],
   [0.04511007],
   [0.04312284],
   [0.0451733 ],
   [0.04560687],
   [0.04263394],
   [0.04183227],
   [0.048634  ],
   [0.05198746],
   [0.05615724],
   [0.05787913], dtype=float32)
```

then i transformed it in 2d array

```py
array2d = np.reshape(dataset, (-1, 2))
```

now i have

```py
array([[0.0417634 , 0.04493844],
   [0.04932728, 0.04601787],
   [0.04511007, 0.04312284],
   [0.0451733 , 0.04560687],
   [0.04263394, 0.04183227],
   [0.048634  , 0.05198746],
   [0.05615724, 0.05787913],
   [0.05989346, 0.0605077 ], dtype=float32)
```

Now i'm going to calcolulate the mean between each element of the array

```py
paa = []
paa.append(array2d.mean(axis=1))
```

now i want a list of intervals from this list

```py
intervals = paa[::10]
intervals
```

but the result is the same list (paa). Why? Already tried to convert it in np.array(paa)

Expected a new list with less elements. Since 10 is the nr of steps i'm expecting [0.0417634, ... paa[11], .... paa[21] .... ]

Comment: What do you expect `paa[::10]` to do, exactly?

Comment: Please include your expected output

Comment: expected a new list with less elements. Since 10 is the nr of steps i'm expecting [0.0417634, ... paa[11], .... paa[21] .... ] @GPhilo

Comment: in that case, `paa[0]` **is** `array2d.mean(axis=1)`. Perhaps you meant `paa = array2d.mean(axis=1).tolist()` (although there are better ways to do this than passing through lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.mean` will return a `np.array`. You are taking the result and appending it into a `list`. When you are slicing it, you're getting the `0th` (and only) element in `paa`, which is an entire `np.array`.

Get rid of the `list` and append and slice directly into the result of mean.